# Set active menu item inside menu

Tags: extjs, menu, menuitem

I am trying to dynamically set an  active item inside a menu as if it was selected. Browsing through the documentation I could not found a solution. I am trying to this while rendering the whole menu.

```
caseListStore.each(function(n) {

        var menuItem = new Ext.menu.Item({
            text: rec.data.name,
            value: rec.data.url,

        });

        if (rec.data.name == "someCondition)" 
           menuItem.setActive();     //not working

        casesMenu.add(menuItem);
});
```

Comment: What means "not working"? There is a `)` missing.

Comment: That is not the problem. Actually nothing happens.

Comment: What exactly do want the menuitem to do by `setActive()`?

Comment: I want to set that item to be selected or active if you want. As if it was clicked.

Comment: Do you want it to be clicked or just look like?

Comment: I want it to be the active one when the rendering is done. And yes clicked(selected)

Comment: I am not sure what "active" means for you. Can you run that simple code and verify the `setActive` does what you want? `Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    items: [{
        text: 'i dont get active'
    },{
        text: 'i get active',
        handler: function( item ) {
            item.setActive();
        }
    }]
});`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: Check out the code editor in the docs, paste the code there: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item

Comment: The code doesn't work in the viewer. To make things clear again. Let's say I have a menu with with 5 items. How can I dynamically set for example the 2nd item to be active like if it was actually clicked by the user.

Comment: Run the following code in the code editor: `var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    width: 100,
    plain: true,
    floating: false,  // usually you want this set to True (default)
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  // usually rendered by it's containing component
    items: [{
        text: 'plain item 1'
    },{
        text: 'plain item 2'
    },{
        text: 'plain item 3',
        handler: function( item ) {
            menu.setActiveItem( item );
        }
    }]
});`

Comment: Also, I cannot see any visible change on the menu item after I click it. I do not know what should happen actually. Can you take a screenshot of what an "active" item looks like?

Comment: Ok you clearly don't understand. Don't bother anymore

Comment: You  need to be a little more specific on your needs. Do you want to activate it as in a toggled state? Have all the Items visible at afterrender instead of clicking the parent to diplay them? Or just fire the onClick event on a particular MenuItem? Also read the API on [setActive()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item-method-setActive), I don't think its supposed to have any visual impact.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `setDisabled`?

```
    menuItem.setDisabled(true);
```

If you are using ExtJS 3.4, please use the `disable` function.

```
     menuItem.disable();
```

Comment: Why would I use setDisabled if I want to activate an item

Comment: Is the same think, y can use setActive(true) or setActive(false), the difference is that setActive fire activate and desactivate events or setDisabled not fire events.

Answer (score -2):

You better use the *setActiveItem* method of your menu, **after** the menu item was added to the menu

```
caseListStore.each(function(n) {

    var menuItem = new Ext.menu.Item({
        text: rec.data.name,
        value: rec.data.url,

    });

    casesMenu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem.on("afterrender", function(){
       if (rec.data.name == "someCondition)" 
           casesMenu.setActiveItem(menuItem); 
    }



});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But nothing happens. The default menu is still choosen. Instead I get an error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

Comment: Did you let the menu render **before** setting the active item?

Comment: Better put your activation code in a function that handles the afterrender event of the menu item.

Comment: It works but only if the menu is clicked. Because menu items are rendered when you click on a menu. I want it to be automatic

Comment: Under documentation it doesn't even have a setActiveItem() method
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-method-setActiveItem Marked private, so check out their code http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Menu.html#Ext-menu-Menu-method-setActiveItem how it is used in the framework.

Comment: Please do not rate down my answer, it just did not solve your problem completely.